# SIGSEGV for Column-wise matrix using string concatenation in Fortran

Tags: matrix, fortran, string-concatenation, segmentation-fault

I am trying to read a column of a flowfield snapshot (uvw stacked, ~24k of them) and assemble multiple snapshots (which are saved into a individual .dat files, as seen in the code posted) into a matrix (columns are velocities at timesteps, i=1 first timestep, ect) for use in SVD/POD. I followed some tutorials on here and got the formatting down (I think) but now am stuck as I am getting this sigsegv error. Any input is much appreciated. Thanks!

```
       program matrix2       
!      Creates rectangular matrix by adding columns of individual
!      Timesteps for use in Singular Value Decomposition (in MatLAB)

!      Allocate
       double precision, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: POD
       integer, parameter :: tend = 700
       integer, parameter :: length = 23925
       character(:), allocatable :: fn, fm
       integer :: it, idt
       character(len=5) :: t, dt
       character(len=10) :: fmt
       character(len=40) :: fmm

!      Create format discriptors
       fmt = '(i5.5)'
       fmm = '(a19,i5.5,a4)'

!      Create data file to save matrix
       fn = 'POD_Data_Matrix.dat'
       open(unit=1,file=fn,status='unknown',form='formatted')

!      Loop to open column files and write data
       do j = 1,tend

!      Open corresponding column file, add to POD matrix
!      and close every timestep column
!      Convert integer to string using internal file
         it=00001
         idt=00001
         write(t,fmt) it
         write(dt,fmt) idt
         fm = 'U-Matrix-Column-Eq-'//trim(t)//'.dat'
         open(unit=11,file=fm,status='unknown',form='formatted')  
         do i = 0,length
           read (11,*) POD(j,i)
         enddo
         close(11)
         it = it + idt
       enddo

!      Write and close final POD matrix
       write(1,*) POD(j,i)
       close(1)

!      Deallocate
!       deallocate(POD)
!       deallocate(fn,fm)
       endprogram
```

Comment: The use of allocatable deferred length character means that your code requires Fortran 2003.  The code uses many other language features that require Fortran 90+.  Not much Fortran 77 here!

Answer (score 0):

`POD` is declared to be an allocatable, but it is never allocated prior to the attempted definition in the READ statement.  Perhaps you forgot to allocate it with something like   `ALLOCATE(POD(tend,length))` prior to the reading loops?